# Not working show and hide accordion? where is problem

Tags: html, css

There is a "show preview" / "hide preview" button that appears in edit mode between the textarea and the preview container. This toggle allows, well, to show and hide this preview.
So of course I thought that would solve my problem, until I realize that all it does is to set a display: none on the container.

-> NOT WORKING :( WHY

```css
.panel-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.panel-title {
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid #FEE4CF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 15px 65px 15px 20px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.manulo.cz/user/documents/upload/sablona/arrow-down.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 20px center;
}
.flex-between-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.panel-title > div:first-of-type {
    max-width: 540px;
}
.flex-center-wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.in-doprava-a-platba .panel-title > div img {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.panel-body {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 20px 25px;
}
.type-page .content-wrapper-in ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.type-page .content-wrapper-in ul li {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.type-page .content-wrapper-in ul li::before {
    content: '';
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #AE6830;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 6px;
}

.panel-show + .panel-body {
    display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
.panel-title {
    background-size: 20px auto;
    background-position: right 10px center;
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 15px;
}
.panel-title > div > span, .panel-title > div > p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.panel-title.panel-show + .panel-body {
    background-color: #FEE4CF;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #FEE4CF;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}
.panel-show + .panel-body {
    display: block;
}
.panel-body {
    padding: 0 20px 25px;
        display: none;
}
.panel-body {
    padding: 0 15px 25px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-item">
<div class="panel-title flex-between-center">
<div class="flex-center-wrap"><img src="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/446290.myshoptet.com/user/documents/upload/sablona/ppl.svg"> <span>PPL</span></div>
<div><span>99&nbsp;Kč</span></div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<ul>
<li>Když nakoupíte od 1900 Kč, máte dopravu zdarma. Jinak doručení stojí 99 Kč.</li>
<li>doručení a kontaktem na řidiče pro pohodlnější domluvu.</li>
<li>zkusí to ještě následující pracovní den. Následně váš balík uloží na nejbližší PPL zasielka.</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

where is problem not show and hide..

Comment: Is there any JavaScript that goes with this?

Comment: If you're not using any JS or `:active` or `:focus` pseudo element, then nothing will happen as you use no 'trigger' element to open/close some detailed information. Without JS, often the 'checkbox hack' is used. But, why don't you investigate the `details` and `summary` elements as they are perfectly suited for showing some additional info when a user clicks/taps the summary: [MDN: details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

Comment: @rene-van-der-lende Thank you, where to add active and focus to make it work? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is

- to change the `.panel-title` into an *anchor tag* `<a>`, making it an element that can receive *focus*.
- and with CSS *combinator selector* `+`, the `.panel-body` can be toggled in/visible when the `<a>` loses/gets focus using the `:focus` *pseudo selector*.

I made those changes for you and added a second `panel-item` in `<body>` so you can see the *accordion mechanism* at work.

I also removed obsolete `.panel-show` references and cleaned up the `@media`.

**Notice** the two `href="javascript:void(0)"`, without a `href` defined, an `<a>` cannot receive focus making the *accordion* fail to work...

Check the below **snippet**

```css
/* NEW */

.panel-title {
  /* To override standard <a> markup */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: currentColor;
}

.panel-title:focus+.panel-body {
  /* make it visible */
  display: block;
}


/**/

.panel-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.panel-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 110px;
  border: 1px solid #FEE4CF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 15px 65px 15px 20px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/www.manulo.cz/user/documents/upload/sablona/arrow-down.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 20px center;
}

.flex-between-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.panel-title>div:first-of-type {
  max-width: 540px;
}

.flex-center-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.in-doprava-a-platba .panel-title>div img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.panel-body {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 20px 25px;
}

.type-page .content-wrapper-in ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.type-page .content-wrapper-in ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.type-page .content-wrapper-in ul li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #AE6830;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 6px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .panel-title {
    background-size: 20px auto;
    background-position: right 10px center;
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 15px;
  }
  .panel-title>div>span,
  .panel-title>div>p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  /* Cleaned the clutter and removed obsolete code */
  .panel-title:focus+.panel-body {
    background-color: #FEE4CF;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #FEE4CF;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    padding: 0 15px 25px;
  }
  /**/
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-item">
  <a class="panel-title flex-between-center" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <div class="flex-center-wrap">
      <img src="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/446290.myshoptet.com/user/documents/upload/sablona/ppl.svg"> <span>PPL</span>
    </div>
    <div><span>99&nbsp;Kč</span></div>
  </a>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
      <li>Když nakoupíte od 1900 Kč, máte dopravu zdarma. Jinak doručení stojí 99 Kč.</li>
      <li>doručení a kontaktem na řidiče pro pohodlnější domluvu.</li>
      <li>zkusí to ještě následující pracovní den. Následně váš balík uloží na nejbližší PPL zasielka.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <a class="panel-title flex-between-center" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <div class="flex-center-wrap">
      <img src="https://cdn.myshoptet.com/usr/446290.myshoptet.com/user/documents/upload/sablona/ppl.svg"> <span>PPL</span>
    </div>
    <div><span>99&nbsp;Kč</span></div>
  </a>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
      <li>Když nakoupíte od 1900 Kč, máte dopravu zdarma. Jinak doručení stojí 99 Kč.</li>
      <li>doručení a kontaktem na řidiče pro pohodlnější domluvu.</li>
      <li>zkusí to ještě následující pracovní den. Následně váš balík uloží na nejbližší PPL zasielka.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```